# python ConfigParser: read configuration from string

Tags: python, string, replace, newline, configparser

I would like to parse a configuration string that I receive from a service and read each single paramenter.
The string result is `[section 1],var1 = 111,var2 = 222`

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ConfigParser
import io
[...]

result = decoded['result']
result = result.replace(',', '\n');
print result
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(io.BytesIO(result))
print config.get("section 1", "var2")
print config.get("section 1", "var1")
```

using:

```
res = """
[section 1]
var1 = 111
var2 = 222
"""
```

it works so I believe is something wrong with `result.replace(',', '\n');` but if I print the result seems good.
Any suggestion please?

Thank you
dk

Comment: Can you write the output of `print repr(result)`

Comment: Dear Xavier, here the result `u'[section 1]\nvar1 = 111\nvar2 = 222'`

Comment: fixed it with 
`result = result.encode('ascii','ignore')`

Comment: It is not the good way to fix it, please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. It was an unicode error. Next time please show the stack trace

```
result = u"""
[section 1]
var1 = 111
var2 = 222
"""
print repr(result)
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(io.StringIO(result))
print config.get("section 1", "var2")
print config.get("section 1", "var1")
```

output:

```
u'\n[section 1]\nvar1 = 111\nvar2 = 222\n'
222
111
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for this called `read_string` on the `ConfigParser` object.

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.read_string(result)
```

Comment: the above code throwing the below error. globals.CF_currFile=config.read_string('CustomFile','LastCustomFileAccessed')
**AttributeError: RawConfigParser instance has no attribute 'read_string'**